# Inline SQL Not Updating

Tags: sql-server-2008

My print statement fails each time and so does my exec, anytime I try to run this statement it just tells me command completed successfully.  I added the print statement to try to see what was actually being executed, but I am still mind-blown on this.  Can someone here please help me?

Shouldn't the Print statement at least show me what I am trying to run?  If I print each variable individually before trying to run the update it shows the correct value, so I can only assume it is something way wrong with my update statement?

```
Declare @fulldata varchar(30), @rsi varchar(50), @employeename varchar(50), @email varchar(50), @rsi2 varchar(50), @email2 varchar(50),
    @rsiID varchar(50), @calldate datetime, @calltime datetime, @orderdate datetime, @email3 varchar(50), @uniqueID int, @sql varchar(max)  


Set @fullData = 'tvdb'
Set @rsi = 'Alphabet'
Set @employeename = 'Mike Jones'
Set @email = '123abc@gmail.com'
Set @rsi2 = 'Broccoli'
Set @email2 = 'abc123@gmail.com'
Set @rsiID = 'alt16bc'
Set @calldate = '06/15/2015'
Set @calltime = '12:15:00'
Set @orderdate = '06/16/2015'
Set @email3 = 'pineapple1841@gmail.com'
Set @uniqueID =     172855  

    Set @sql = 
    'update '+@fulldata+' '
    + 'set rsi = COALESCE('''+@rsi+''',''''), '
    + 'employeename = COALESCE('''+@employeename+''',''''), '
    + 'email = COALESCE('''+@email+''',''''), '
    + 'rsi2 = COALESCE('''+@rsi2+''',''''), '
    + 'email2 = COALESCE('''+@email2+''',''''), '
    + 'rsiID = COALESCE('''+@rsiID+''',''''), '
    + 'calldate = COALESCE('''+CAST(@calldate As Varchar)+''',''''), '
    + 'calltime = COALESCE('''+CAST(@calltime As Varchar)+''',''''), '
    + 'orderdate = COALESCE('''+CAST(@orderdate As Varchar)+''',''''), '
    + 'email3 = COALESCE('''+@email3+''','''') '
    + 'where uniqueID = '+CAST(@uniqueID As Varchar)+' and '+CAST(@uniqueID As Varchar)+' > 0 '
    Print @sql
    exec (@sql)
```

EDIT ---
If I try to insert my statements into a table to check it is null.  Which leads me to why is @sql not being assigned?

```
Insert Into #SqlStatement (sql12) VALUES (@sql)

Select * FROM #SqlStatement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have all lines included here? and you can run it without error?

At least your don't have declaration of @sql.

Even you declare the @sql, this line will give you error:

```
  Set uniqueID =  172855
```

It should be

```
 Set @uniqueID =  172855
```

Without assigning values to @uniqueID, your whole @sql is be NULL and print will generate NO output.

```
  update tvdb set rsi = COALESCE('Alphabet',''), employeename = COALESCE('Mike Jones',''), email = COALESCE('123abc@gmail.com',''), rsi2 = COALESCE('Broccoli',''), email2 = COALESCE('abc123@gmail.com',''), rsiID = COALESCE('alt16bc',''), calldate = COALESCE('Jun 15 2015 12:00AM',''), calltime = COALESCE('Jan  1 1900 12:15PM',''), orderdate = COALESCE('Jun 16 2015 12:00AM',''), email3 = COALESCE('pineapple1841@gmail.com','') where uniqueID = 172855 and 172855 > 0 
  Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
  Invalid object name 'tvdb'.
```

To debug your code, you can comment out some lines like:

```
Set @sql = 
'update '+@fulldata+' '
+ 'set rsi = COALESCE('''+@rsi+''',''''), '
---+ 'employeename = COALESCE('''+@employeename+''',''''), '
----+ 'email = COALESCE('''+@email+''',''''), '
----+ 'rsi2 = COALESCE('''+@rsi2+''',''''), '
----+ 'email2 = COALESCE('''+@email2+''',''''), '
----+ 'rsiID = COALESCE('''+@rsiID+''',''''), '
----+ 'calldate = COALESCE('''+CAST(@calldate As Varchar)+''',''''), '
----+ 'calltime = COALESCE('''+CAST(@calltime As Varchar)+''',''''), '
----+ 'orderdate = COALESCE('''+CAST(@orderdate As Varchar)+''',''''), '
----+ 'email3 = COALESCE('''+@email3+''','''') '
----+ 'where uniqueID = '+CAST(@uniqueID As Varchar)+' and '+CAST(@uniqueID As Varchar)+' > 0 '
Print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

and uncomment one line a time until you find the problematic line.

To catch values and make sure you have a non-null @sql, you need use the COALESCE this way:

```
Set @sql = 
  'update '+@fulldata+' ' ...
  + 'email = '''+COALESCE(@email,'')+''','
```

Comment: I updated that in my syntax, and still sql is printing no results.  But if I print each variable individually They have results.

Comment: it's printing on my studio. Are you sure you are using the exact code?

Comment: Even when I try to hardcode the uniqueID in my query by doing 'where '@uniqueID = ''1458''  My print statement is null

Comment: you may have some other code issues. without seeing your final code, i have no idea. the posted code works for me. if you don't want to post your code, try debug it by commenting out lines using "-----"

Comment: thank you for the debugging tip.  rsi is null which is causing my @sql to be null.  I thought I would handle a null value with my Coalesce statement is that not accurate?

Comment: The problem is if one of the values is null, your sql is null. "Coalesce" are not even called yet. To check nulls when constructing the sql, you need put the Coalesce outside the quote marks. See my edited answer.